# Find a point on a plane that is closest to the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the closest point to the origin on the plane which is tangent to $f(x,y)=x^2 e^y$ at point $P(0.9,0.1)$.

Comment: Are you asking what point on the tangent plane is closest to the origin?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: Please show us how far you can get with this, and where you are having trouble?  Can you find the tangent plane, for example?

Comment: I can only find the linearization but not the tangent plane that estimates the function as there are only 2 variables x and y, and I need a value of z

Comment: I think that the problem should say, "at the $P(0.9,0.1,f(0.9,0.1)).$

Comment: but it only says P(0.9, 0.1)

Comment: You've changed the wording of the question a bit, though.  It's talking about the plane which approximates the graph of the function near $(.9,.1).$  If you're talking about the tangent to the surface, it's tangent at the point $(.9,.1,f(.9,.1))$  It's just a matter of semantics.  As you yourself have said, you need a third coordinate to fix the plane.

Comment: so how can I find the plane that approximates the graph of the function near (0.9,0.1) ?

Comment: I go back to my earlier comment.  Edit the body of the question to show us what you have done so far.  This is not a "do my homework for me" site.  If you show us where you're having trouble, we'll try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the figure with the function in yellow, the tangent plane (to be computed, below) in blue, and $P$ in red.  Note the non-uniform scaling in different axes:

[image]

The function is:  $f(x,y) = x^2 e^y$

The derivatives with respect to $x$ and to $y$, are:

$2 x e^y$ and $x^2 e^y$, respectively, which when evaluated at $P$ have values:

$1.98931$ and $0.895188$.

Thus the tangent plane has the form:

$z = 1.98931 x + 0.895188 y + c$, where $c$ must be found so that the plane goes through $P$:  $c = -0.984709$.

Now we want to find the point on this plane $z = 1.98931 x + 0.895188 y -0.984709$ that is closest to the origin.  Compute the (square) of that distance:

$d^2 = x^2 + y^2 + (1.98931 x + 0.895188 y -0.984709)^2$.

Take the derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$, set them to zero and find:

$x^* = 0.340158$ and $y^* = 0.153071$.

Note the uniform scaling in this figure, and the confirmation that the green separation line to the origin is perpendicular to the tangent plane.

[image]